# Salvar vários dados em Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, laravel, controller

Tenho o seguinte formula no meu blade, e agora quero salvar os dados de cada linha no meu banco de dados. Como salvar esses dados em Laravel?

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++){
        var minhaData = moment(DataVencimento).add($i, 'months');
        ParcelaVencimento =  minhaData.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
        var linha = '<tr class="selected" id="linha'+cont1+'">    <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="apagar('+cont1+');"> X </button></td>      <td> <input type="hidden" name="cont1[]" value="'+cont1+'">'+cont1+'</td>  <td> <input type="text" name="ParcelaVencimento[]" value="'+ParcelaVencimento+'"></td> <td> <input type="number" name="ParcelaValor[]" value="'+ParcelaValor+'"></td> </tr>'
        cont1++;
  }
```

Tentei fazer isso no meu Controller para salvar mas esta voltando o erro
      **"count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"**

```
public function store(BoletoFormRequest $request){           
        $ParcelaVencimento=$request->get('ParcelaVencimento');
        $ParcelaValor=$request->get('ParcelaValor');

        $cont = 0;
        while($cont < count($QtdParcela)){
        $Boleto = new Boleto();
        $Boleto->ParcelaVencimento=$ParcelaVencimento[$cont];
        $Boleto->ParcelaValor=$ParcelaValor[$cont];
        $Boleto->save();
        $cont=$cont+1;
       }
}
```

Sou iniciante, qual o melhor método para salvar esses dados?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que não exista o melhor método, mas existe alguns padrões que podemos seguir. Vou passar um exemplo que sigo.

Rota:

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/uri', 'arquivoController@store')->name('nomeDaRota');
```

Controller:

```
public function depositStore(MoneyValidationFormRequest $request){

    $ParcelaVencimento = $request->get('ParcelaVencimento');
    $ParcelaValor = $request->get('ParcelaValor');
    $QtdParcela = $request->get('QtdParcela');

    $response = $store->armazenar($ParcelaVencimento, $ParcelaValor, $QtdParcela );

    if ($response['success']){
        return redirect()
                    ->route('rotaHome')
                    ->with('success', $response['message']);
    }

    return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->with('error', $response['message']);

}
```

Model:

```
    public function armazenar($parcelaVencimento, $parcelaValor, $qtdParcela){           

        try {

        $cont = 0;
            while($cont < count($QtdParcela)){
              $Boleto = new Boleto();
              $Boleto->ParcelaVencimento=$ParcelaVencimento[$cont];
              $Boleto->ParcelaValor=$ParcelaValor[$cont];
             // DB : Tratamento para commit ou Rollback

              DB::beginTransaction();

              $Boleto->save();

              DB::commit();

              $cont=$cont+1;
           }

           return [
                    'success' => true,
                                    'message' => 'Boletos registrados com sucesso!'
                ];

        }catch(\Exception $e){
            DB::rollBack();
            return [
                'success' => false,
                                'message' => 'Falha ao registrar boleto. ERRO : ' . $e->getMessage()
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

Acredito que você consiga se basear nesse exemplo aplicado ao seu codigo. eu não entendi muito bem a variavel $qtdparcela, por isso talvez o codigo nao funcione.